# How many n strings are there of letters of english alphabet in which there are no consecutive z's?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, combinatorics-on-words

I have this combinatorics problem:

> How many n strings are there of letters of english alphabet in which there are no consecutive z's?

I want to solve this problem using generating functions

Generating functions of single letters other than z is obvious but i can't find the generating function for z. I know that its function will be a polynomial with degree of $\frac{n}{2}$ or $\frac{n+1}{2}$ depending on whether n is even or odd but i can't find the coefficients of the function. Can anyone lead me to a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, it's easy to solve recursively...if the length is at least $2$ then any good string of length $n$ is a either a good string of length $n-1$ followed by a character other than $x$, or it is a good string of length $n-2$ followed by a pair $*x$ where $*$ is any character other than $x$.

Comment: I believe you would want an exponential generating function: $$g(x) = \sum_{n\ge 0} a_n\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$$ because then you have $$g(x) = 25g'(x)+26g''(x)$$ if I am not mistaken.

Comment: That 26 should be 25 i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The letter $z$ is always followed by a non-$z$, except for the $z$ at the end. So group each $z$ with letter after it to form a double letter. The string is built out of letters and double letters; call each of these a "unit". The generating function of a single unit is $25x+25x^2$; there are $25$ letters of length $1$, and $25$ double letters of length $2$. Since we want a sequence of these units, the g.f. is
$$
{1\over 1-25x-25x^2}
$$
But wait, we forgot about the possible $z$ at the end! There either is or is not a $z$ at the end, which is accounted for by a factor of $1+x$. Therefore, the answer is actually
$$
\bbox[5px,border:1.5px solid black]{{1\over 1-25x-25x^2}\cdot (1+x).}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Words with no consecutive equal characters at all are called Smirnov or Carlitz words. See example III.24 *Smirnov words* in *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html)* by Philippe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick for more information.

A generating function for the number of Smirnov words over an $n$-ary alphabet is given by
\begin{align*}
\left(1-\frac{nz}{1+z}\right)^{-1}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> Here we consider an alphabet with $n=26$ letters. Since there is only a restriction given for $z$, all other letters may occur with runs of arbitrary length. We respect this by substituting each of these characters with
>
> \begin{align*}
> z\to z+z^2+z^3+\cdots=\frac{z}{1-z}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> We substitute (2) in (1) for all characters but one and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> &\left(1-\frac{z}{1+z}-25\frac{\frac{z}{1+z}}{1+\frac{z}{1+z}}\right)^{-1}\\
> &\qquad=\color{blue}{\frac{1+z}{1-25z-25z^2}}\\
> &\qquad=1+26z+675z^2+17\,525 z^3+455\,000z^4+11\,813\,125z^5+\cdots
> \end{align*}
>   The last line was calculated with some help of Wolfram Alpha.

Answer (score 0):

Or,
we can build a good word by adding, step by step, a new component

$sA + sB + \cdots + sY + sZ + s^2.c.ZZ + s^3.c^2.ZZZ + \cdots \ $   where

$c$ is a counter for the **at least** number of occurrences of a pair ZZ in the word.

$s$ is a counter for the length of the added component.

overall the strings are depicted by

$$1 \over 1 - (sA + sB + \cdots + sY + sZ + s^2.c.ZZ + s^3.c^2.ZZZ + \cdots )\ $$

we are interested in words that have **exactly** $ \ 0 \ $ occurences of ZZ, so we have to replace $ \ c \ $ by $ \ c-1 \ $ for the PIE reason, than take $ \ c=0 \ $.

the generating expression becomes $${1 \over 1 -(  sA + sB + \cdots + sY + {sZ \over 1+sZ}) }={ 1+sZ \over 1 -(  sA + sB + \cdots + sY )(1 + sZ)}$$

when we are interested only in length ( the sort of letter does not matter)  we get the generating function

$$  \frac {1+s} {1 - 25s.(1 + s)} $$